# Unable to get Data from Serial Device using Arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino, sensors

I am trying to read the data from a Ultra Sonic Fuel Sensor([the link](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ultrasonic-fuel-sensor_1875683281.html)).The Baud rate of this device is 9600.The device basically sends data at regular time intervals.I am able to read the output in the PC using Terminal software.Given below is a sample.

**Eg:*XD,205B,00,0000,0031,0000,0000,null#**

I am trying to connect this device to Arduino through serial port provided in the device and when I see the Serial Monitor,the output is not correct.Given below is the sample.

**5320215115451166102572432302302432302302302302432303816623024323023023023024323023023023051822281141463**

```
String incoming_char;      // Will hold the incoming character from the Serial Port.

void setup()
{
  //Initialize serial ports for communication.
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting Communication with Fuel Sensor");
}
void loop()
{

 //If a character comes in from the cellular module...

  if(Serial1.available() >0)
  {
    incoming_char=String(Serial1.read());    // Get the character from the cellular serial port.
    Serial.print(incoming_char);  // Print the incoming character to the terminal.
  }
}
```

The Arduino is powered from USB and the Device from a 12V supply.
The voltage levels from the device Tx-GND=-5.44V,Rx-GND=-8.22V.

I initially thought the the issue might be because of the voltage range and made a voltage divider circuit and fed Arduino the proportionate voltage.Even that is not working.
So,what is the thing which is going wrong ?Please guide me.

Comment: You are confuzzling ASCII and binary data.  *Something* is displaying the characters in the string as integers instead of characters.

Comment: Ya Hans,I switched to Serial.write and now it is printing junk Characters.Apparently,This character set is the getting converted to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all ! for your Value inputs.The problem was, I was trying to connect RS232 Serial(Works with Negative Voltages) to TTL serial interface(Works with 0 to some Positive Voltages) used in Arduino. Apparently,I was supplying negative voltages to Arduino whereas it was expected to give Positive voltages. So, got a RS232-to-TTL connector and it worked,finally.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Serial1 I am assuming you are using an Arduino Mega?

From your question I would say the issue isn't voltage etc. but more likely to be how you are reading the data. You are assuming that the sensor will be returning char values. Are there any specifications on what is being returned?

I created a similar project using an Arduino. Except my Ultrasonic device was used as a range finder. There are details [here](http://ianjamesharris.com/?page_id=17). As you can see in the code the range is returned from the sensor as a two byte integer.

You will need to find out what the what the Ultra Sonic Fuel Sensor is returning and read in a similar fashion.

Comment: Hi GolgiDevang,I am using Arduino Mega 2560.Actually,the specification says that it uses ASCII and it is of the format "(*XD, efgh, ij, klmn, abcd, opqr, stuv, wxyz #).

Comment: Ok am I right in thinking that you are using Serial to communicate with your LCD display? Have you tried printing something hard coded to the screen. Also I notice that the sensor description has two output's RS232 and analog. Are both output simultaneously or is there a switch? Did you test on your PC using RS232 with a DB9 connector?

Comment: Hi GolgiDevang,I am just using the Serial interface as the data required is given only in the serial output.I did test with the DB9 connector and it showed me outputs.Seems,the problem is solved now.Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

allright i  would start by suggesting that you connect this to an analog pin to read. you will have to find the ratio between the fuel hight and voltage by measuring and dividing. then insert the multiplication in the code and you are set it will look like the hight instead of just a voltage

Comment: Hi user3792207,The thing is ,we are not just looking only for the height.We are looking for Surface temperature,Signal Quality which happens to be part of this Serial output.

Comment: oh all right i am sorry i can't help you then. I am relatively new at this. sorry i could not be of more help i hope your project goes well

Comment: No problem user3792207..Even, I am New to this.Seems, I have crossed one hurdle.Hopefully shall cross others as well.Thanks for your Inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess since I don't own an Arduino Mega (I have Duemilanove and Uno), but I've worked on projects wherein I've encountered issues similar to what you have. Sometimes adding a `delay()` on your `void loop()` block helps and gives it enough time for the arduino to read the bytes from the buffer. For 9600 baud rate, it usually takes about 1 ms to read 1 byte so adding a delay is necessary.

```
void loop()
{

 //If a character comes in from the cellular module...

  if(Serial1.available() >0)
  {
    incoming_char=String(Serial1.read());    // Get the character from the cellular serial port.
    Serial.print(incoming_char);  // Print the incoming character to the terminal.
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Hi GRIMM..Thanks for your inputs.